# Specify app root when packaging Trigger.io web app for release

Tags: trigger.io

A packaged Trigger.io web app references its Forge assets in index.html with an absolute path:

```
script src="/_forge/all.js"
```

Is it possible to make this path relative or to otherwise specify an "app root" for instances in which the nodejs web app will be served from a non-root path on the web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently no - the `/_forge/all.js` reference is not configurable.

I take it you're deploying this as part of, or associated with, another Node app? We can certainly make that configurable, if you're not able to have that path serve `all.js` - get in touch at support@trigger.io to discuss timings.

Comment: If all.js wasn't assumed to be at the root of the path it would be possible to deploy multiple trigger node apps to the same domain name using something like mod_proxy to direct requests to the corresponding nodejs host and port. I would like to differentiate each app via a path name instead of host name: myhost.org/trigger_app_1 and myhost.org/trigger_app_2.

Comment: Would a relative import be sufficient then, e.g. ../_forge/all.js or similar? That's much easier for us to do than configurable deployment roots: could get that into the next version of our platform.

Comment: Right, I'll include that in our next platform version: will be going live in about a week or so.